# how to grab output from tcpclient on serial port

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I am trying to grab the output from a tcpclient application that I cannot change. I know that it is running since another application can connect to it but it's written in VB6 and I don't have the code.

Here is what I have so far:

```
  public static void Main()
  {    
    try
    {
      // Set the TcpListener on port 13000.
      Int32 port = 5107;
      IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

      // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
      TcpListener server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

      // Start listening for client requests.
      server.Start();

      // Buffer for reading data
      Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
      String data = null;

      // Enter the listening loop.
      while(true) 
      {
        Log("Waiting for a connection... ");

        // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
        // You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here.
        TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();            
        Log("Connected!");

        data = null;

        // Get a stream object for reading and writing
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        int i;

        // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
        while((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))!=0) 
        {   
          // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
          data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
          Log(String.Format("Received: {0}", data));

          // Process the data sent by the client.
          data = data.ToUpper();

          byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

          // Send back a response.
          stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
          Log(String.Format("Sent: {0}", data));            
        }

        // Shutdown and end connection
        client.Close();
      }

    }
    catch(SocketException e)
    {
      Log("SocketException: " + e.Message);
    }

  }
```

**UPDATE HAD WRONG LINE HERE**
The problem is, it is stopping at `TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();` and doing nothing from there.

The other application is running but it's not connecting (?) I guess. I've not worked with tcp like this before so I'm not sure what I'm doing.

I am positive the port is correct also.

How do I grab the output from the client if it isn't connecting?

**======= EDIT =======**

This is the code from the application I am trying to get the information from:

```
 Private Sub SendToPPS(ByVal GPS_Message As String)
    If mbDebug_PPSGS Then
      LogToFile("Starting Sub SendToPPS")
    End If
    Dim CloseSocket As Boolean
    LogToFile("Starting SendToPPS")

    If PPSIsRunning() Then
      LogToFile("PPSIsRunning")
      CloseSocket = False
      If mbDebug_PPSGS Then
        LogToFile("SendToPPS() PPS is Running.  Sending: " & GPS_Message)
      End If
      ' Don't try to send to PPS if PPS is not running

      Try
        ' Create a TcpClient.
        ' Note, for this client to work you need to have a TcpServer 
        ' connected to the same address as specified by the server, port
        ' combination.
        If SocketClient Is Nothing Then
          ' The socket is not open yet.  Open it now. 
          Dim port As Int32 = 5106
          SocketClient = New TcpClient("localhost", port)
        End If

        If SocketClient2 Is Nothing Then
          ' The socket is not open yet.  Open it now. 
          Dim port As Int32 = 5107
          SocketClient2 = New TcpClient("localhost", port)
        End If


        ' Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
        Dim data As [Byte]() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(GPS_Message)

        ' Get a client stream for reading and writing.
        Dim stream As NetworkStream = SocketClient.GetStream()
        Dim stream2 As NetworkStream = SocketClient2.GetStream()

        ' Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
        stream2.Write(data, 0, data.Length)

      Catch err As ArgumentNullException
        LogToFile("SendToPPS() ArgumentNullException: " & err.ToString)
        CloseSocket = True
      Catch err As SocketException
        LogToFile("SendToPPS() SocketException: " & err.ToString)
        CloseSocket = True
      End Try
    Else
      CloseSocket = True
      LogToFile("SendToPPS() PPS is Not Running.")
      ' PPS is not running
      ' Make sure Socket is closed
    End If

    If CloseSocket Then
      If Not SocketClient Is Nothing Then
        Try
          SocketClient.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
          LogToFile("SendToPPS() Closing Socket Exception: " & ex.ToString)
        End Try

        SocketClient = Nothing
      End If

    End If

    If mbDebug_PPSGS Then
      LogToFile("SendToPPS() Ending Sub SendToPPS")
    End If

  End Sub
```

**======= EDIT #2 =======**

Both of these applications are running on the same computer so that is why I am using 127.0.0.1.

Comment: If it fails at `new TcpListener`, I suspect your OS is blocking the port.

Comment: I put the wrong line that it was stopping on:  TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();  is the line it is just sitting on not moving.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the clarifications, that's helpful.

At a high level, your code looks good.  You're probably getting stuck in the 'while(true)' part of the code, not on the 'server.Start();'  This would be consistent with the client not connecting.

I'd suggest attaching a debugger to both sides of the connection.  Since you have the source code, I would assume you have the symbols and can get a debug build.  Combine this with a network monitor like [NetMon](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865) and you should be able to work out what is failing where.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the program that is spewing out the information is running a tcpclient that I need to connect to, does that mean I also need a tcpclient to receive it's information?

Comment: The 13000 was from the example given by microsoft. I have the right port.